# Someone hacked into my account and changed my name, how do I change it back?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My profile is *3xtremeGamerz*, I was playing a game and then I went to a different server and my name changed to some serious swearing and slurs. It happened after I relaunched Minecraft. I'm still on my profile but the name is still the same. How do I change it because I'm not gonna play any other servers with that name?

Comment: It's not possible for them to change your username, except on their server(s).  Try joining a different server.

Comment: Join a single player world and type something into chat. If your name is affected, contact mojang support and change your passwords. If not, then the change is only on that particular server.

Comment: It has been changed by someone, I have edited my answer with a link to show you. I'm sorry to say that you have been hacked.

Comment: If your IGN has been changed by another person, you can change it in 30 days.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to get a username like that. Mojang are trying their best on the censorship of usernames. The most likely answer is that someone did something like `/nick (your username) (the new username)` as a troll or something.

I would recommend going into a single player world and typing something in chat. If it is the same then contact Mojang support immideatly and change your password to a really complex one.

EDIT: Contact Mojang support now. [**This here**](http://namemc.com/s?3xtremeGamerz)  shows you that someone has changed your name and when. Also when you can next change your name back manually. You have to act now for your security's sake.

Comment: you're going to have to wait until august 2nd to change it back, unless you contact mojang and have them change it for you

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me. Just scan your computer for malware, remove it, then change your password and rename yourself back to normal.